# Why is order by required inside OVER when using LEAD in SQL?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT seller_name, sale_value,
  LEAD(sale_value) OVER(ORDER BY sale_value) as next_sale_value
FROM sale
ORDER BY sale_value
```

Am I right to understand that lead must compulsorily have over(order by..) because the SELECT is executed before the final ORDER BY statement?

Comment: Addition to the below correct answer: you are also right, it is indeed being executed before, because the final ORDER BY controls the sorting of the result for representation, but the logic in the OVER clause could define another ordering and is independent of representation order.

Comment: See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement) also, however window functions are not highlighted separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` is required in the `OVER` clause, not in the outer query.  So this is fine:

```
SELECT seller_name, sale_value,
       LEAD(sale_value) OVER (ORDER BY sale_value) as next_sale_value
FROM sale;
```

However, the results may be in any arbitrary order.

Why does `LEAD()` require the `ORDER BY`?  Well the definition of `LEAD()` is to pull the value from the "next" row.  However, SQL tables represent *unordered* (multi)sets.  There is no next row unless a column or expression defines it -- and that is what the `OVER ( . . . ORDER BY)` defines.